# create a new calendar entry in the notes client out of an xpage in the browser

Tags: xpages

"I don't" like the way myself" ... but at the moment I have no other chance to solve this task: Therefore I am looking for a way to create a new calendar entry (appointment) in the user's notes client, from a button in an xpage the user has opened in his browser.

I tried it with sth like "notes://server/mailpath/Appointment?CreateDocument", but this only opens his mailDB in his notes client, but do not create a new Appointment.

Thanks for any help - Uwe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet does exactly that:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-calendar-entry-with-ssjs

Comment: And if you wonder what all these fields do, check the [Lotus Notes Calendar Schema](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc) on developerworks